# jQuery toggle with multiple animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a site and when someone clicks the contact link, in the nav, a contact box appears and slides down. The nav then moves down to remain below the contact box (that just appeared). The issue is when you click the contact link again the toggle hides the contact box but leaves the nav down where it would be if the contact box was still visible. Here is the code:

```
contactBarBtn.click(function (e) {
    search_close();
    contactBar.toggle();
    navbarFixedTop.animate({ top: contactBar.height() }, 'slow'),
    contactBar.animate({ top: '0' }, 'slow'),
    contactCorner.css('display', 'block'),
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are the statements separated by commas ?

Comment: Not sure. That is how the script came.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
contactBarBtn.click(function (e) {
    if (jQuery('.contact-bar-corner').css('display') == 'block') {  
        search_close();
        navbarFixedTop.animate({ top: '0' }, 'slow');
        contactBar.animate({ top: -contactBar.height() }, 'slow');
        stickyHeader.removeClass('sticky');
        contactCorner.css('display', 'none');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    else if (jQuery('.contact-bar-corner').css('display') == 'none') {  
        search_close();
        contactBar.show();
        navbarFixedTop.animate({ top: contactBar.height() }, 'slow');
        contactBar.animate({ top: '0' }, 'slow');
        stickyHeader.addClass('sticky');
        contactCorner.css('display', 'block');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent -- you can probably use `jQuery('.contact-bar-corner').is(':visible')` instead of `jQuery('.contact-bar-corner').css('display') == 'none'` but that is a minor style thing. Sorry, I got a really bad cold and didn't get a chance to make a JSFiddle. I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `top: contactBar.height()` will run before `contactBar.toggle()` has finished -- in fact, it will run almost right away. So instead, you need to move that into the `toggle` to get called when the toggle animation is finished:

```
contactBar.toggle(function() {
  navbarFixedTop.animate({ top: contactBar.height() }, 'slow');
});
```

Also, the lines should end with `;` not `,` as the commenter mentions!

Comment: It still remains there when I click it the second time. The contact box is disappearing but the nav is not returning to the top. I tried adding a second function and the same code but adding a -contactBar.height() but then the link stopped working.

Comment: Here is the code

`contactBar.toggle(function(){
     navbarFixedTop.animate({ top: contactBar.height() }, 'slow'),
        contactBar.animate({ top: '0' }, 'slow'),
        stickyHeader.addClass('sticky'),
        contactCorner.css('display', 'block'),

  },function(){
    navbarFixedTop.animate({ top: -contactBar.height() }, 'slow'),
        contactBar.animate({ top: '0' }, 'slow'),
        stickyHeader.removeClass('sticky'),
        contactCorner.css('display', 'none'),
  });`

Comment: @JosephManning Hrm, I think we need a JSFiddle as there is too much going on -- I suspect you need to keep track of the original top value and put that back in when toggle is closing.

Comment: The js has a close option of 

`function contact_close() {
        contactBar.animate({ top: -contactBar.height() }, 'slow');
        contactCorner.css('display', 'none');
    }`

I apologize I've never used jsfiddle and am having a hard time getting this site to work.